# Update one UserControl from another UserControl in WPF application

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I create two user controls in WPF application.

1 ) HolidayList.xaml
2 ) HolidayEdit.xaml

I have one method on HolidayList control called LoadData().

```
Public Sub LoadData(ByVal lCnd As String)
...........
End Sub
```

Now on Holidayedit control I have Insert/update code for Holiday.I want to update the gird after Insert/update operation.for that i write following code on my closewindow event.

```
 Dim lst As New UC_HolidayList

 lst.LoadData("")
```

but this code not reference the grid.I have to load data again by pressing Load button.

Please let me know if someone have idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to create an event ?

Comment: what do you mean by  
"Do you know how to create an event ? "

Comment: User Control events..

Comment: Or for a beginner, he can create an event in UserControl1. Subscribe to it in the owner window. Raise it when update data in UserControl1. Then call the methods of UserControl2 from owner window.

Comment: I have to call save button event for usercontrol2 first and than need to call usercontrol1 loaddata method.